# BeautifulSoup will only return None

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Im learning Beautiful Soup and I dont know what I could be doing wrong, I'm using soup.find on an id, and Ive tried this on multiple different sites, and I run it and it always returns None.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

site = 'https://www.amazon.com/PlayStation-5-Console/dp/B09DFCB66S'
headers = {'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.45 Safari/537.36'}

def stock_check():
    page = requests.get(site, headers = headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
    title = soup.find('span', id = 'productTitle')
    print(title)


stock_check()
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 errors in your code:
1.incorrect locator
2.not invoking text
3.not inject cookies
Now your code is working fine:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

site = 'https://www.amazon.com/PlayStation-5-Console/dp/B09DFCB66S'
headers = {'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.45 Safari/537.36'}
cookies={'session':'141-2320098-4829807'}
def stock_check():
    page = requests.get(site, headers = headers,cookies=cookies)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
    title =  soup.find('span', attrs={'id':'productTitle'})
    print(title.get_text(strip=True))


stock_check()
```

Output:

```
PlayStation 5 Console
```

Answer (score 0):

The answers of HedgeHog and Fazlul are of course correct, but I want to comment on this.

When you scrape something from the web and try to extract tags from the HTML but get nothing, first check the whole HTML document you recieved to make sure it's what you expected. Personally I just print out `soup.prettify()` to debug this, as explained in [BeautifulSoup's Quick Start](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#quick-start):

[image: Example 1]

Another nifty trick if the HTML is impractical to read is to paste it into a HTML previewer like [this one](https://www.onlinehtmleditor.net/), and we get the answer quickly.

[image: Example 2]

**BeautifulSoup can be a great tool, but you need to pay attention when using it.**